# Graphic Tablet For Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop PC

Tags: graphics-tablet

I'm looking for a budget graphic tablet (something around £30) for my Ubuntu 18.04 OS. I can't get my current one (XP Pen G430) to work with Ubuntu. Which tablet brands have drivers that are well supported by Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you find anything compatible?

Comment: i gave up on this. sorry.